# How to determine the core number of GPU except refer its document?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

I want to figure out the core number of the `GPU`, but it seems it can't be got from `information` file:

```
/proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:04:00.0 % cat information
Model:           Tesla K80
IRQ:             122
GPU UUID:        GPU-0f4524b9-e951-f4d5-94ad-ac3b80f6b4f8
Video BIOS:      80.21.1f.00.01
Bus Type:        PCIe
DMA Size:        40 bits
DMA Mask:        0xffffffffff
Bus Location:    0000:04:00.0
Device Minor:    0
```

Except referring the [doc](https://images.nvidia.com/content/pdf/kepler/Tesla-K80-BoardSpec-07317-001-v05.pdf), is there any method to find out the core number of the `GPU`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used it, but as its an NVIDIA CPU, maybe something like [CUDA-Z](http://cuda-z.sourceforge.net/) will tell you what you want to know ?

The screenshots show how man multiprocessors/cores, threads per multiprocessor and a whole lot of other performance info as well.